# Writing to textbox inside an unselected tab

Tags: c#, textbox, serial-port, tabcontrol

I have a program that can read and write on serial, GPIB, USB, and Ethernet.  It has a tab for each method of communication with a textbox inside that displays communication on the port.  One of the tabs is listed as All Comms and that text box has data from all communication methods.  I am currently working on the serial port portion of the code and my program keeps freezing.  Half the time I run my code it functions without issue writing to both tabs.  The other half it freezes up when it tries to write to the text box inside the tab that is not selected(found by stepping through the code a line at a time).

I pulled the text boxes outside the tab control and this fixes the freezing issue.  When the program freezes it does not display an error message and does not crash so no crash report(left it running over the weekend and it never finished crashing).

I would think that I need to select the other tab and then write to it, but why would the code work correctly half the time I run it?

[Image of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puGrs.png)

```
        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        rxString = rxString + serialPort1.ReadExisting();

        if (rxString == "\b")
        {
            //Removes 1 character when backspace is the key pressed
            rxSerialTextBox.ReadOnly = false;
            rxSerialTextBox.Select(rxSerialTextBox.TextLength - 1, rxSerialTextBox.TextLength);
            rxSerialTextBox.SelectedText = String.Empty;
            rxSerialTextBox.ReadOnly = true;
            rxString = "";                
        }

        while (rxString.Length != 0)
        {
            try
            {
                while (rxString.Length != 0)
                {
                    if (rxString.IndexOf("\r\n") == 0)
                    {
                        //Adds a newline when newline is the next characters in the string
                        rxString = rxString.Substring(rxString.IndexOf("\r\n") + 2);
                        rxAllCommsTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                        rxSerialTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                    //Adds a new character to the text box
                    rxAllCommsTextBox.AppendText(rxString.Substring(0, 1));
                    rxSerialTextBox.AppendText(rxString.Substring(0, 1));
                    rxString = rxString.Substring(1, rxString.Length - 1);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //rxString = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quck look at the `SerialPort.DataReceived` event [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) brings into attention the following **Remarks** section paragraph:

> The DataReceived event is raised on a **secondary** thread when data is received from the SerialPort object. Because this event is raised on a secondary thread, and not the main thread, attempting to modify some elements in the main thread, such as UI elements, could raise a threading exception. If it is necessary to modify elements in the main Form or Control, post change requests back using Invoke, which will do the work on the proper thread.

According to this, your code that touches UI elements (text boxes) inside that event handler is incorrect. What the documentation doesn't say is that when you do so, the behavior is undefined - sometimes it may work, another time hang, yet another time throw exception.

So, instead of asking why your incorrect code sometimes work, you'd better concentrate on making it correct, and only then if something is not working, ask why and seek for a solution.

P.S. I'm not going to address how the concrete issue can be solved - there are a tons of posts, explanations and examples of how to marshal the calls to the UI thread, and in that regard there is nothing special in your case.

Answer (score 0):

It was a little confusing your question ...

you can try, it is understood correctly, try to keep the value you want to assign the memory context, and assign the value based on another type of iteration.

At the moment the application freezes, which shows the breakpoint? The expected behavior does it work?

I would try a configuration object, such as a list, with various configurations, and certain state, the amount you need to pass the list to the tabcontrol. Obviously, it needs to check what's not working and why is not ...